# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ITurnContext'

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I'm using QNA maker in my chatbot project using Bot Framework and I want to take the question from the adaptive card and send it to the QNA maker but I'm getting an error says: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ITurnContext'

```
public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var value  = turnContext.Activity.Value;
        if (value != null)
        {
            var val = value.ToString();
            var relationsJSON = JToken.Parse(val);  
            var text = relationsJSON["text"].ToString();
            if (text == "car model")
            {
                var result = await QnAMaker.GetAnswersAsync(text);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(result[0].Answer, cancellationToken: cancellationToken); 
            }
        }
}
```

the error message on: var result = await QnAMaker.GetAnswerAsnyc(text);

Answer (score 0):

The `QnAMaker.GetAnswerAsnyc` method is always expecting the `ITurnContext` as a mandatory parameter. So you can't inject any other parameter in the respective method.

So try the below code here JSON text is assigned to `turnContext.Activity.Text` object. Because as per your code `OnTurnAsync` method is always validating `turnContext.Activity.Value` object.

```
public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var value  = turnContext.Activity.Value;
    if (value != null)
    {
        var val = value.ToString();
        var relationsJSON = JToken.Parse(val);  
        turnContext.Activity.Text = relationsJSON["text"].ToString();
        if (turnContext.Activity.Text == "car model")
        {
            var result = await QnAMaker.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext.Activity.Text);
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(result[0].Answer, cancellationToken: cancellationToken); 
        }
    }
}
```